# How to update Email-To-Case Settings Email Address

Tags: case, sandbox-refresh, email2case

I want to update email address associated with email to case settings after refresh in my sandbox. I want to complete this using apex code, is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: I couldn't find anything to generate these addresses. I am afraid it is more of an administrative activity.

Comment: i typically include the staging E2C address in my production org so when sandbox refresh occurs, I have it available for use

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to update E2C is via the Setup UI.

However, `OrgWideEmailAddress` is a metadata type that can be accessed in SOQL.

```
select id, DisplayName, Address from OrgWideEmailAddress
```

If you can locate the relevant address, you should be able to update it via DML.